# How to get the result in string form from JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, gsm

I'm studying android development and studying the program code listed below. Please tell me how to get a string value from this code fragment.
That is, String GSMINFO = "type = gsm, lac = ..., cid = ..., psc = ..."
Thank you all for your help, sorry for the bad English.

```
public static String gsmCellLocationJSON(GsmCellLocation location) {

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        if (location != null) {
            try {
                json.put("provider", CELLLOCATION_PROVIDER);
                json.put("type", GSM);
                json.put("timestamp", calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                json.put("cid", location.getCid());
                json.put("lac", location.getLac());
                json.put("psc", location.getPsc());
            } catch (JSONException exc) {
                return "error";
            }
        }

        return json.toString();
    }
```

I don't understand the mechanism of the return

Comment: The JSONObject class contains a method called getString(String name). For example you could say json.getString("type"). As long as the value you passed in, GSM is a string, you can retrieve this value.

Comment: Could you help with an example?
How do I translate the result of the code into the variable a, and then set it to the value of textview?

Comment: I am confused about the question. I understand you convert your object to JSON, but why would you need to retrieve it after from the JSON. Is it saved to a file and then you read the JSON from the file? You could try something like this `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonContent); String type = json.getString("type");` In this case jsonContent would be the JSON string created by the gsmCellLocationJSON method.